# Create a boxplot with regression line using matplotlib

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have a data frame with a column for "year" and a column for variable "FrostDays", with multiple values for each year.  I want to create a boxplot showing the distribution of values for each year, and add a regression line showing the change in the average number of FrostDays over a 50-year period.

I can create the boxplot and the linear regression plot separately, but I cannot get Python to plot the two simultaneously on the same graph (on the same axis).  The result should have ~50 box plots with the y-axis showing FrostDays and the x-axis showing the year, and a regression line going through the boxplots according to the linear model.

```
# Create the linear model

x = PRISM_FD_A.year
y = PRISM_FD_A.FrostDays
stats = linregress(x, y)
m = stats.slope
b = stats.intercept
xmin = min(PRISM_FD_A.year)
xmax = max(PRISM_FD_A.year)
ymin = min(PRISM_FD_A.FrostDays)
ymax = max(PRISM_FD_A.FrostDays)
prd = max(PRISM_FD_A.year) - min(PRISM_FD_A.year)
ch = m * prd
ch_FD = ch.astype(int)
string = ("Total Change: %s days over %s years") % (ch_FD, prd)
r = stats.rvalue
r2 = round(((r)**2), 3)
rstring = "R-squared: %s" % r2

# Create the boxplot

ax = PRISM_FD_A.boxplot(by='year',
                       column='FrostDays',
                       grid=False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
plt.show()
```

[Boxplot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ngcW.png)

```
# Create the regression line:

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Annual Count of Frost Days \n Ashokan Basin', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85, bottom=0.15)
ax.set_title(string, fontsize=10)
ax.set_xlabel("year \n Source:  PRISM", fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel("Number of Frost Days", fontsize=10)
ax.plot(a_x, a_m * a_x + a_b, color="red", linewidth=3)
fig.text(0.80, 0.015, rstring, color='white', backgroundcolor='royalblue',
         weight='roman', size='medium')
ax.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
plt.show()

# Join the two together:

fig = plt.figure()
fig.suptitle('Annual Count of Frost Days \n Ashokan Basin', fontsize=14, fontweight='bold')
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.85, bottom=0.15)
ax.set_xlabel("Year", fontsize=10)
ax.set_ylabel("Number of Frost Days", fontsize=10)
PRISM_FD_A.boxplot(by='year',
                       column='FrostDays',
                       grid=False)
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.MultipleLocator(5))
ax.plot(a_x, a_m * a_x + a_b, color="red", linewidth=3)
fig.text(0.80, 0.015, a_rstring, color='white', backgroundcolor='royalblue',
         weight='roman', size='medium')
ax.axis([xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax])
plt.show()
```

I get a plot with just the regression line and no box plot.

[Regression line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DDQGf.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the figure axis for the `pandas` boxplot using `ax=ax`.

```
PRISM_FD_A.boxplot(by='year',column='FrostDays',ax=ax,grid=False)
```